# Rounded UIButton - iPad size

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have custom UIButton to have rounded edges

```
import UIKit

class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "map.png")!)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "map.png")!)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

}
```

Now I am using this "RoundedButton" (size of 110, 110) in a UIViewcontroller's XIB file and the constraints are set to maintain the aspect ratio w.r.t UIViewcontrollers view.

The button looks rounded in iPhone simulators but the button is NOT rounded in iPad simulator. When I set the layer.cornerRadius property in viewDidAppear then the button is rounded in iPad simulator.

Please see images

[image]

[image]

I am looking for an alternative solution than re-defining layer corner radius again in viewDidappear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override layoutSubviews function:

```
import UIKit

class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "map.png")!)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "map.png")!)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

override method layoutSubviews like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width * 0.5
}
```

Also you can now remove cornerRadius line from init

For more go to documentation of UIView: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width / 2
    }
}
```

I have also create a code sample for you. [RoundedButton](https://github.com/devadvent/RoundedButton)